# Equivalent of Cisco's logging synchronous CLI command on Dell PowerConnect switch

Tags: networking, command-line-interface, dell-powerconnect

When using the CLI of cisco devices, there is the "logging syncronous" command that keeps the log messages from interrupting the command prompt. Do Dell PowerConnect switches have a similar command somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the CLI manual, the feature is not available.

Answer (score 0):

The user enables events or monitor traps from the CLI by entering the command
logging console. Traps generated by the system are dumped to all CLI
sessions that have requested monitoring mode to be enabled. The **no logging
console** command disables trap monitoring for the session. By default,
console logging is enabled.

console# no logging console

Get Support on Twitter: @DellCaresPro

Comment: That's not quite what I was looking for. I still want to see the log messages. Is there a way to have the console prompt and what I've typed re-displayed after the log message has been displayed?